# Opera - Prevent input from having focus

Tags: jquery, html, input, cross-browser, opera

I have a hidden input on one of my pages, and by hidden, I mean visible, but just looks like plain text.

Take for example http://jsfiddle.net/imoda/nVhp8/

But I don't want a user to be able to click in it and edit the information.  Essentially disabling it, but without setting it to `disabled` in the html.  I think I'm close but whatever I've tried isn't working.

Seems to work in everything except Opera.  Help please?

Comment: Why exactly would you need such an input?

Comment: When you click an edit button the input becomes "live", gets it's border back, etc.  Similar to editing a Google contact.

Comment: What is wrong with the example you posted in the link ?

Comment: Looks like it's Opera specific, I'll change the question.

Comment: This looks like asking how to do something you shouldn't be attempting in the first place. One usability law is that unless you're Facebook, you should be sure that interacting with your site works like people expect from other sites. It might make sense to have an input type="hidden" and also have its content present in the text; it does not make sense to keep the input element as an input element but try to force it to act like something else. Think a little further outside the box (or, as the case may be, inside the box) next time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using jQuery, why not simply use the `readonly` attribute, removing that attribute once the edit button has been clicked?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nVhp8/5/).

References:

- [`readonly`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-readonly).

Comment: Even better.  That way people can still select the text.  Thanks.

Comment: firefox still allows you to focus and move a cursor around inside the input.  granted you can't type anything but it's still less than ideal

Answer (score 4):

Use a timeout..

```
$("input").focus(function(){
    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function(){_this.blur();},1);
});
```

and a more extended example at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/nVhp8/2/

Comment: I used `$(this).hasClass('inactive')` but same difference.  This works okay in Opera but has funny effects in other browsers (check chrome or opera).  If you click and drag in the field you still get the browser's "glow" around the field.  Also, if you double click "World" in your example, you can drag it over in front of "hello".  This is getting there but I think there should be a better solution.