# How to block all input on everything beyond specified container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Here's what I'm trying to do. There is a CMS system with quite a "javascriptifyed" UI controls. Many custom types of inputs, lots of events, assigned to each, etc. My task is to block some fields from changing, without making them "disabled" (so that they're not ignored when data is sent to the server). I don't have control over anything that application and other widgets do, before my own widget is loaded. And by this time, there is lot of stuff already (events assigned, etc.)

Current implementation is something like this:

```
    blockField: function($input)
    {
        if ($input.length===0) { return; }

        $input.prop('readonly', true);

        // Workaround for calendar widget
        if ($input.hasClass('date_field')) {
            $input
                .removeClass('date_field')
                .addClass('text-input');
        }

        var $valueCell = this.getFieldContainer($input);
        $valueCell.on('focus', '*', function(event) {
            this.error(this.w_code, 'One cannot simply change this field!');
            return false;
        }.bind(this));
    },
```

This does not work very well with all kinds of widgets, however. There are some other drawbacks as well.

So, the idea is to intercept all events on their way *down* to the widget's container and stop their propagation any deeper.

My naïve attempt is the following:

```
        $valueCell.get(0).addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            this.error(this.w_code, "Just don't…");
            return false;
        }.bind(this), true);
```

It seems to prevent "click" from being passed through the container ($valueCell); however, similar trick does not work with "focus" event — it a sneaky fellow. I've tried to block it on the `$input` itself, with `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` — with no luck.

Is there someone who actually solved a problem like this?

Comment: check the accepted answer, I think it is a right way to do it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700297/opera-prevent-input-from-having-focus

Comment: @Gatsbill I've already setting readOnly. It does not prevent element from being focused. In fact, it has only cosmetic meaning (the input changes its look on focus), but I'd like to avoid it anyway.

[screensot](https://www.evernote.com/l/ACg2Su1rep5NBbjgBDYfMcd6pGmxOLbgmpsB/image.png)

Answer (score 0):

There's a CSS property: 'pointer-events', which has helped with preventing fields from becoming "focused".

Here's the final implementation:

```
function blockFieldsInside($container)
{
  $input = $container.find('input,textarea,select');

  // Make all controls read-only:
  $input.prop('readonly', true);

  // On the "capture" leg of event bubbling (it's important)
  // we stop all intercepted clicks
  $container.get(0).addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // probably overkill (returning false anyway)
    e.stopPropagation(); // probably overkill (returning false anyway)
    alert('No.');

    return false;
  }, true);

  // This fixes drop-downs from opening via keyboard:
  $container.on('keydown keyup', '*', function () {
    return false;
  });

  // Don't "tab" onto blocked fields:
  $input.each(function () {
    $(this).prop('tabindex', -1);
  });

  // The final accord:
  $('*', $container).css({ pointerEvents: 'none' });
}
```